# Syntax error: Identifier directly after number

Tags: javascript

I'm using a library which has colours defined this way: 500_. Every mention of this inside the library's code throws a syntax error.

It works fine on my friend's computer, how do I fix this?

Palette.js:

```
import { alpha } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function createGradient(color1, color2) {
  return `linear-gradient(to bottom, ${color1}, ${color2})`;
}

// SETUP COLORS
const GREY = {
  0: '#FFFFFF',
  100: '#F9FAFB',
  200: '#F4F6F8',
  300: '#DFE3E8',
  400: '#C4CDD5',
  500: '#919EAB',
  600: '#637381',
  700: '#454F5B',
  800: '#212B36',
  900: '#161C24',
  500_8: alpha('#919EAB', 0.08),
  500_12: alpha('#919EAB', 0.12),
  500_16: alpha('#919EAB', 0.16),
  500_24: alpha('#919EAB', 0.24),
  500_32: alpha('#919EAB', 0.32),
  500_48: alpha('#919EAB', 0.48),
  500_56: alpha('#919EAB', 0.56),
  500_80: alpha('#919EAB', 0.8)
};
```

Error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/theme/overrides/Input.js
Syntax error: Identifier directly after number (24:53)

  22 |         underline: {
  23 |           '&:before': {
> 24 |             borderBottomColor: theme.palette.grey[500_56]
     |                                                      ^
  25 |           }
  26 |         }
  27 |       }
```

Error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/charts/BaseOptionChart.js
Syntax error: Identifier directly after number (20:50)

  18 |         border: '0 !important',
  19 |         fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
> 20 |         backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.grey[500_16]} !important`,
     |                                                   ^
  21 |         color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  22 |       },
  23 |       '.apexcharts-xaxistooltip-bottom': {
```

Comment: What version of Node are you running? What about your friend? [Numeric separators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#numeric_separators) are supported from NodeJS 12.5.0

Comment: Try wrapping the key on quotes: theme.palette.grey["500_56"]

Comment: We're both on version 16.4.1

Comment: Where do you see this error? What are you _running_ to produce it?

Comment: I'm running npm start, these files are from the library

Comment: This is purely a Babel issue. See [babel/babel#9631](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9631), [facebook/jest#9768](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9768) and [babel/babel#7660](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7660) for some hints

Comment: @Phil Not "purely", but a look at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-numeric-separator makes sense if a friend's computer differ

Comment: You can try putting it into a string, like `myObj["500_16"]`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to everyone that helped, it is indeed a babel issue.

In short, install globally to fix:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator
```

Comment: not work for me(

Answer (score 2):

**Put it simple: on defining properties JS knows that *500_16* should be a string, on reading properties you have to tell it.**

That's some inconsistency in JS leading to an edge case: *500_16* is a valid property *name*, but not a valid property *accessor*, i.e. you cannot use dot notation `myObj.500_16`, but have to use bracket notation - and now with bracket notation you can only use the valid property name types *identifier name*, *string literal*, or *numerical literal*. *500_16* is none of that: identifiers cannot start with a number, strings have to be enclosed in quotes, and numbers cannot contain *_*, instead it looks like valid number *500* followed by a valid identifier *_16*. So you have to put *500_16* in quotes.

Check it and find details on https://mothereff.in/js-properties.

Some complication might brought in by ES2021 introducing "Numeric Separators" (see again [Mathias Bynens](https://v8.dev/features/numeric-separators)). *_* interpreted by your browser as a numeric separator would make *500_16* a correct number *50016*, as well in defining as in reading properties. In such a scenario no "Identifier directly after number" error would arise, but `myObj[500_16]` would not retrieve the property `500_16`, but return `undefined` for a property `50016`.